# ASIO data format

Tags: audio, asio, dataformat

I'm planing to build a simple audio interface. For that I just want to know in which format the ASIO drivers deliver data to a program usually? I couldn't figure that out of the specifications or find that somewhere else. I don't want to write an own driver, I just want to deliver my data in the same format.

Comment: Have you subscribed to the Steinberg ASIO development page? You can download specifications and SDKs with a sample parogram. That should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some ASIO development, and from testing on 7 systems with 10 different soundcards (internal and external), most of them use ASIOSTInt32LSB and some use ASIOSTInt16LSB for *output*. With these two formats implemented, I've yet to see a soundcard that uses anything else.

Of course this is just plain old trial and error and not an exact approach by any means.